# how to print barcode with zebra printer programming language

Tags: zebra-printers

^BY3,3,102^FT389,54^BCI,,Y,N
^FD>:TC>502261601^FS

Can someone explain to me what how this barcode works? What does the >5 mean?When I remove the >5 the barcode prints too long to fit on the label. The reason I would like to remove the >5 is because I'd like to the barcode data TC02261601 to be variable and Id set it programitcally..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most applications there is no need to be specific in the barcode command as to which subset of Code 128 should be used, such as inserting '>5'. You can let the printer handle it by (1) specifying 'Auto' mode in the BC command, and (2) just specify the barcode content, i.e., TC02261601.

Answer (score 1):

Code 128 has 3 subsets, A is numerics, upper-case alphas and control characters. B is numerics, upper- and lower-cse alphas. Subset C in numeric-only.

In A and B, each character occupies 1 symbol. In C, one symbol represents 00..99 so the code fore numeric-strings is reduced in length.

`>:` initially invokes subset `B` (which is the default, so it's not required in the above code)

`>5` changes from subset `A or B` to subset `C`. Without it, the characters following are produced in subset `B`, not `C` and hence the code is longer.

So - it depends on your data.  `>5` switches from subset `B` to `C` and `>6` from `C` to `B`.

If your data is all-numeric, use `>;` to start the code, which invokes subset `C` to start.

Start codes:

```
`>9` Start code `A`
`>:` Start code `B` (default)
`>;` Start code `C`
```

Switch codes:

```
`>5` `A` or `B` to `C`
`>6` `A` or `C` to `B`
`>7` `C` or `B` to `A`
```